# When does a referral fee become bribery? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, bribery

If a company makes an offer like this:

> Thanks for using the free product. If you think your company would
>   benefit from the advanced features of the premium product, please tell
>   the [person responsible for purchasing]. If they sign up, your company
>   will receive a £50 discount and I will send you a £50 Amazon voucher.

Is this a simple referral fee, or could it be construed as bribery (under English law)?

Comment: Note also that employers commonly have strict rules regarding gifts from suppliers and clients. So while this sounds like pretty normal sales practice to me, you may have to declare the gift voucher, and may not be allowed to keep it.